# pass json data from controller to view

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, controller, c3

Partial View :

```
var dataa;
    $.ajax({
        url: ServerUrl + '/Dashboard/GetData',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        async: true,
        error: function (xhr) {
            //alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            dataa = result;
            var chart = c3.generate({
                data: {
                    type: 'bar',
                    json: [
                        dataa
                    ],
                    keys: {
                        x: 'indicator',
                        value: ['total']
                    }
                },
                axis: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'category'
                    }
                },
                bar: {
                    width: {
                        ratio: 0.5
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Controller Json code

```
public string GetData()
{
return "{ 'indicator': 'X', 'total': 100 },{ 'indicator': 'Y', 'total': 200 },{ 'indicator': 'Z', 'total': 300 }";
}
```

When i use the above code it doesn't work  but if I pass json data as specified in [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2erLqgx/2/) link, it works. Am I passing the JSON data incorrectly from controller.?

Please help.

Comment: Its not valid (your returning a string, not json) - it would need to be `[{indicator: 'X", total: 100}, {...}]`. You would be better off creating a collection of objects with properties `indicator` and `total` and then `return Json(myCollection);` so its valid.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : is this a valid string 

return "{ \"indicator\": \"X\", \"total\": \"100\" },{ \"indicator\": \"Y\", \"total\": \"200\" },{ \"indicator\": \"Z\", \"total\": \"300\" }";

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I just have to test it with the hardcoded json data passed from controller. Please help me with the same

Comment: You would need to test it. But its a string, not json. Use `public JsonResult GetData()  return Json(....)` }` to return valid json data. Also you ajax option needs to be `dataType: 'json',` (not 'text')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not return JSON from method GetData.
Do this way to return JSON

```
public JsonResult GetData()
   { 
       var data = new[] {
          new { indicator= "X", total = 100 },
          new { indicator= "Y", total = 200 },
          new { indicator= "Z", total = 300 }
       };

           return  Json(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

And make ajax call like:

```
 $.ajax({
         cache: false,
         type: "GET",
         url:URL,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (result)
         {
           console.log(result);
         },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
         {
          alert('Failed to retrieve data.');                    
         }
       });
```

Comment: 3 errors to fix: It needs to be `return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`, the ajax option needs to be `dataType: 'json',` and in the success callback, it needs to be `data: { type: 'bar', json: dataa, ...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Thanks a lot ... You both are life savers

Comment: @111 : How can fill the above data array dynamically from a type of Dictonary<string,int>. I need to fetch data from DB and display.

Comment: You can use JavaScriptSerializer for that. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx.                 var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var serialized = jsSerializer.Serialize(data);